# Android emulator takes very long to load applications on MOST networks

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

So I have been automating tests for a mobile application using Android Emulator and Appium. On most networks, it takes very long for the application to load (which is heavily dependant on API Calls for information displaying). Even when connected to my home network through an ethernet cable and wifi (100MBps download - 30MBps upload) it takes almost 1min30sec to load this app on Emulator... When I turn on hotspot on my phone through mobile data (which has a lower speed than my home network), the app loads in like 5-8 seconds... I truly don't know what is happening.. I literally used up 25GB of mobile data in a span of a week testing this app, almost any other network (home wifi/eth - public wifi - hotspot from other mobile phone) takes also to load very long. I have connected to 1 wifi network that did load it fast, but this is not always accessible. (When switching from the 'slow' to the 'fast' loading network, I don't restart anything, as soon as the connection is changed, the app loads way faster. Yes I tried restarting everything too, managing IPv6 connections, etc..)

I find this to be a very weird problem and haven't really encountered any other threads tackling this issue. The phone that makes it load faster has 5G connection, but the hotspot is set to 2,4Ghz. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you loading?:  The app itself (installing the app)?  Are you talking about launch speed?  Why do you think it has anything to do with the network-  have you run it under a profiler and seen that it's always waiting for network IO?

Comment: Not installing the app, just loading it, it stays on the splashscreen and then only loads the app after a few minutes. While on a network of a specific provider, it takes way less. Like a few seconds. In the exact same scenario.
-> When opening first time (specific provider) & running tests: 3-4 seconds
-> When opening second time (specific provider): 3-4 seconds.
vs.
-> When opening first time & running tests on all other networks: +/- 2min
-> When opening second time (not running tests) on all other networks: 30 seconds.

What I mean is open app -> splash screen (time) -> homescreen

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't know if you get notifications when not tagged

Comment: Honestly that sounds like a network problem reaching your host rather than the app.  One thing to try is to just time the network calls themself.  If that's what's taking all the time, then there's nothing wrong with your app on the emulator and everything wrong with the networking setup you're on

Comment: @GabeSechan any ideas where to look when fixing the networking setup? Has it to do with caching, ip-blocking, etc... Much thanks for your input!